# How to authenticate when receiving idocs with ERPConnect (Theobald)?

Tags: idoc, erpconnect

I'm a little lost. I followed the documentation of ERPConnect (Theobald) to setup an rfc server:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
   // define server object and start 
   RFCServer s = new RFCServer(); 
   s.Logging = true; 
   s.GatewayHost = "hamlet"; 
   s.GatewayService = "sapgw11"; 
   s.ProgramID = "ERPTEST"; 
   s.CanReceiveIdocs = true; 
   s.IncomingIdoc+= new ERPConnect.RFCServer.OnIncomingIdoc(s_IncomingIdoc); 
   s.InternalException+= new ERPConnect.RFCServer.OnInternalException (s_InternalException); 
   s.Start(); 

   Console.WriteLine("Server is running. Press any key to exit."); 
   Console.ReadLine(); 
   s.Stop(); 
}
```

The only problem is, that I can't figure out, how to send my password credentials to the SAP server. As a result I get internal exceptions, that I am not authorized to receive idocs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need for any credentials if you want to receive Idocs. Setting up an RFC Server to receive Idocs needs only this 3 SAP Properties: GatewayHost (usually your SAP Server), Gateway Service(usually sapgw + Instancenumber of the SAP System) and ProgramID. You can find a tutorial how to setup the ProgramID following this link:

http://help.theobald-software.com/ERPConnect-EN/default.aspx?pageid=setting-up-an-environment-for-sending-test-idocs

More Details how to receive an Idoc :

http://help.theobald-software.com/ERPConnect-EN/default.aspx?pageid=example-receiving-an-idoc

Best

Ali